# Laravel 5.2 polymorphic model return all where relationship has value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a polymorphic model, named **FeedItem** which is has polymorphic relationships to an **Alert** and **Publication** model.

There is also another model, named **Category**, which the `Alert` and `Publication` models have a `hasMany` relationship to.

**FeedItem**

```
public function feedable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Publication**

```
public function feedItem()
{
    return $this->morphOne('FeedItem', 'feedable');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
```

**Alert**

```
public function feedItem()
{
    return $this->morphOne('FeedItem', 'feedable');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
```

I want to be able to get all `FeedItems` where the `feedable` models have a given `category`.

I've tried:

```
$items = FeedItem::with(['feedable.categories' => function($item) {
    $item->whereHas('feedable.categories', function ($q) {
        $q->where('categories.name', 'my-category');
    })->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate();
```

However, the issue is that the `feedable` relation never gets eager loaded, which prevents the `categories` relationship scoping from being performed.

For example, if I do this:

```
$items = FeedItem::with(['feedable.categories' => function($item) {

    dd('This should be displayed');

    $item->whereHas('feedable.categories', function ($q) {
        $q->where('categories.name', 'my-category');
    })->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate();
```

The `dd()` statement is never called.

Can anyone provide a way of doing this sort of query?

Comment: Have you find a way to do this?